# Why is firebase not recognizing this query?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my query:

```
ref.where(
      "tags",
      "array-contains-any",
      [{ tagTitle: 'webdev' }],
)
```

I know that this query works because if I try it with a 'simple' query, it works.
For example:

```
ref.where(
      "type",
      "==",
      "post",
)
```

However, is there anything else that I have to change than the query, because right now, this is the only thing that I have changed?

This is my firestore collection:
[image]

As you can see, there is a tags field, and I want to select the tagTitle field.

I want to show all the documents with that query, this has worked with the second example. (the `type == post`) one.

But right now I don't get an error, but it also doesn't show in my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you pass both the `id` and the `tagTitle` will it work.

```js
ref.where('tags', 'array-contains-any', [{ id: 480170, tagTitle: 'webdev' }]);
```

Comment: But how do I let the id be anything, because the id won't be the same everytime.

Comment: Then you will have to take the id out from there and save it somewhere else.

Comment: Could you please explain that a bit better?

Comment: How are those id generated ?

Comment: Like this `const newTag = {
        tagTitle: tagTitle.value,
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000),
      };`

Comment: So, I would say that assign id based on the title.

Comment: could it be possible to remove the id and use the tagTitle as the id?

Comment: but do you know how to prevent the tagTitles to be the same?

Comment: You'll have to check that while pushing the data.